# Regex to split and group based on specific phrases?

Tags: java, regex

I need to write a regex that splits a sentence byt the terms may contain or contains.  It may have one or the other or both at least once.

- MAY CONTAIN A,B,C --> (may contain a,b,c)
- CONTAIN X,Y,Z --> (contain x,y,z)
- MAY CONTAIN A,B,C CONTAINS X,Y,Z --> (may contain a,b,c) (contains x,y,z)

How can I build this regex in Java?  In addition, "contain" may be "contain" or "contains"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the regular expression

```
\b(?:may )?contains? [a-z](?:,[a-z]){2}\b
```

with the case-indifferent flag set.

[Demo](http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyEwsSBlJlY2lwZRiAgICyprGBCgw/index.html) (click 'Java')

Java's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
\b          # match a word break (so 'dismay' is not matched)
(?:may )    # match 'may ' in a non-capture group
?           # optionally match the above non-capture group
contain     # match 'contain'
s?          # optionally match 's'
[a-z]       # match a letter
(?:,[a-z])  # match ',' then a letter in a non-capture group
{2}         # execute above non-capture group twice
\b          # match a word break (to avoid matching 'a,b,cat')
```

Recall the case-indifferent flag is set.

Comment: Of course this worked perfectly for my example.  When i went to apply it to a real string like so "MAY CONTAIN A AND B, C, D. CONTAINS X, y, z" i am having issues getting it to match.

Comment: Do you wish to permit any text to appear between "MAY CONTAIN(S)" and "x,y,z" (e.g., "may contain a dog or a cat x,y,z") or only specific text such as "A AND"? If the latter, what text may appear in that part of the string?

Comment: Pretty much "any" text between the groups.  I'm working to split a sentence that the only known delimiter is may contains or contains (and later that can vary in word).  So, each match would start with one of those statement and contain the text up to the next match.

Comment: For that try the regular expression `(?i)\b(?:may )?contains?.*\b[a-z](?:,[a-z]){2}\b`. `(?i)` sets the case-indifferent flag. The text in the middle cannot end with a word character (e.g., `contain some texta,b,c` won't match). [Demo](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyydhatx6r)