# Regex to Split String and Group by Prefix

Tags: java, regex

This "almost" works fully: `\b(?:may )?contains? \w+(?:[,; ]+?\w+){2}\b`

Matching against the below:

- MAY CONTAIN A,B,C
- CONTAINS X,Y, Z
- CONTAIN X,Y,Z
- MAY CONTAIN A B C Contains X;Y Z
- MAY CONTAIN A, B, C
- **MAY CONTAIN A and B; C; D**
- **MAY CONTAIN A and B, C, D and F CONTAINS 1, 2, 3**

Everything works except the last two, they only perform the first match to "B" (MAY CONTAIN A and B)

I basically need to split the sentence on May Contain(s) or Contains.  They could be in any order and the text after/between is pretty variable.

So, I want to separate each match like (MAY CONTAINs ...) and/or (CONTAINs ...).

I used this answer as my base [Regex to split and group based on specific phrases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61945943/regex-to-split-and-group-based-on-specific-phrases/61946012#61946012)

Comment: Your question is omitting something very critical: what do you expect to extract, or what should be the output, from each input you gave above?

Comment: I thought I referenced in the previous question, I basically am expecting a set of matches each starting with "may contain" ... or "contain" ... and the text up to the next match.  In the last bullet, I would expect 2 matches - "may contain a and b, c, d and f" and "contains 1,2, 3)

Comment: Fine, did my comment clarify the output for you?

Comment: You may not like my comments, but IMHO it makes your question clearer, thereby increasing the chances that you will get an answer faster.

Comment: Is `CONTAIN x and y, may contain c, d and e` a valid input?

Comment: The results I expect returns as 2 matches would be (in the case above):
- contain x and y (match 1)
- may contain c, d and e (match 2)
The regex I have in the question, answered from another question, almost does it.  The problem is the text in between - I can figure out how to capture the words after the may contains or contains part up to the next match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the variety of your inputs, you may find this regex more flexible. It matches a string starting optionally with `may`, followed by `contain` with an optional `s`, then everything up to end-of-string or another string starting with the same pattern:

```
\b(?:may )?contains?.*?(?=\b(?:may )?contains?|$)
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OcZQxl/2)